# Uniting within an ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I’m trying to write an ifelse statement (if statement is fine as well) with unite, such that if the number of characters in the FPLACE column were equal to four, it would create a new column called “PLACE_ID” uniting FIPS and FPLACE (in that order, no spaces) and (since all the other characters would be equal to five) to unite the remaining values in the FPLACE column with FIPS_ST and FPLACE and then putting these values also into “PLACE_ID” column.

For the past hour, I’ve been trying some form of this:

```
ifelse(nchar(dat$FPLACE, type = "chars")==4, 
       dat%>%unite(PLACE_ID, FIPS, FPLACE, sep = "", remove = FALSE), 
       dat%>%unite(PLACE_ID, FIPS_ST, FPLACE, sep = "", remove = TRUE))
```

and starting simpler:

```
nchar(dat$FPLACE, type = "chars")==4,
```

which works, but then I try the code below and something goes wrong.

```
if(dat$FPLACE==nchar(4)){
  print(
dat%>%unite(PLACE_ID, FIPS, FPLACE, sep = "", remove = FALSE))
}
```

Ideally, I could just use piping, but even this doesn’t work:

```
dat%>%nchar(.$FPLACE, type = "chars")==4
```

And I think there is something both fundamental and important here that’s hidden in my continual confusion. Why will dat%>%filter(variable=="something") work, but dat%>%nchar(.$variable)==4 won’t? I've also never figured out when you have to use the .$ vs when you don't. What's the rhyme and reason?

Thanks much!!!

dput here:

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3), FSTATE = c("(01) Alabama", "(01) Alabama", 
"(01) Alabama"), FCOUNTY = c(1, 1, 1), FPLACE = c(3220, 62328, 
62328), FIPS_ST = c("01", "01", "01"), FIPS_COUNTY = c("001", 
"001", "001"), FIPS = c("01001", "01001", "01001"), ORI9 = c("AL0040200", 
"AL0040100", "AL0040300"), ORI7 = c("AL00402", "AL00401", "-1"
), NAME = c("AUTAUGAVILLE POLICE DEPARTMENT", "PRATTVILLE POLICE DEPARTMENT", 
"PRATTVILLE FIRE DEPT ARSON INVESTIGATION BRANCH")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), FSTATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), FCOUNTY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), FPLACE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), FIPS_ST = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), FIPS_COUNTY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), FIPS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ORI9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ORI7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), NAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), STATENAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), COUNTYNAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UANAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), PARTOF = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), AGCYTYPE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SUBTYPE1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SUBTYPE2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), GOVID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), LG_NAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_NAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_STR1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_STR2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_CITY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_STATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ADDRESS_ZIP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), REPORT_FLAG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), CSLLEA08_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), LEMAS_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), U_STATENO = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), U_CNTY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), U_POPGRP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), U_TPOP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), LG_POPULATION = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), CSLLEA_SUB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), COMMENT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), INTPTLAT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), INTPTLONG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), CONGDIST1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), CONGDIST2_18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), DISTNAME = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_CSLLEA2008 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_UCR2010 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_UCR2011 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_UCR2012 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_NCIC2012 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SOURCE_VENDOR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure `unite` can be used that way, but you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(PLACE_ID = ifelse(nchar(FPLACE, type="chars")==4, 
                           paste0(FIPS, FPLACE),
                           paste0(FIPS_ST, FPLACE)))
```

Regarding your question about filtering, you filter in a `dplyr` pipe by returning a vector of logical values. For example:

```
dat %>% filter(nchar(FPLACE, type = "chars")==4)
```

This works, because `nchar(dat$FPLACE, type = "chars")==4` returns a vector of logical values. You just need to place it inside `filter` and remove `dat$`, since the data frame is already passed into `filter` by the pipe and you don't need to (and should not) reference the data frame name explicitly.

More generally, you don't need to (and should not) use `data.frame.name$` when referring to column names of a data frame in a dplyr pipe (i.e., when using functions like `filter`, `mutate`, `group_by`, and `summarise`). Just use the bare column names.

For example, see what happens if you do the following with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean1 = mean(mtcars$mpg),
            mean2 = mean(mpg))
```

> ```
>     cyl mean1 mean2
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     4  20.1  26.7
> 2     6  20.1  19.7
> 3     8  20.1  15.1
> ```

```
mean(mtcars$mpg)
```

> ```
> [1] 20.09062
> ```

To calculate `mean1`, we used `mtcars$mpg` instead of the bare column name. This reaches outside the context of the pipe (the "environment" of the pipe in programming parlance) to the version of `mtcars` in the global environment, rather than using the grouped version `mtcars` that was passed into `summarise` by the pipe. Thus, we get the overall mean rather than the grouped mean we wanted.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Your solution worked seamlessly. Re my question, I think I could've been clearer, and I ran into this issue again, just now. For instance, in using your code, if I then try to tack on trimws() at the end of it, it won't work...why is that?:    dat %>% 
  mutate(PLACE_ID = ifelse(nchar(FPLACE, type="chars")==4, 
                           paste0(FIPS, FPLACE),
                           paste0(FIPS_ST, FPLACE)))%>%trimws(PLACE_ID)

Comment: Use `mutate` to make a change to a column in a pipe or to create a new column: `%>% mutate(PLACE_ID = trimws(PLACE_ID))`.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) goes over the basics of using `dplyr` and piping.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look through the tutorial...I should probably use mutate more than I do--I mostly use it when creating a new variable vs altering a current variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put in a plug for case_when, which is more readable if you expand your conditions, and generally leads to less unexpected behavior, here's that version:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(PLACE_ID = case_when(
    nchar(as.character(FPLACE)) == 4 ~ paste0(FIPS,FPLACE),
    nchar(as.character(FPLACE)) == 5 ~ paste0(FIPS_ST,FPLACE),
    TRUE                             ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

Left of the ~ is your condition and to the right is what used if it evaluates to true. Things are evaluated in order until your TRUE (which always evaluates to TRUE, obviously).

As for your question about dplyr and piping, as eipi10 said, dplyr functions work over vectors and assumes that whatever is piped is the data you want to evaluate. The dollar sign is just a shorthand for data[["named_item"]], which just pulls out the named column in the case of data frames. It's essentially the same as passing an arbitrary vector like c(1,2,3) to a function in dplyr; dplyr functions will treat it as static instead of something to vectorize over, which is why the means differ in eipi10's example above. Here's some more information on accessors in R if you're interested:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-accessors-explained/

Comment: Thanks--just found an instance to use case_when. Worked beautifully. Thanks also for your follow-up to my other question...links are always appreciated!

Comment: `"It's essentially the same as passing an arbitrary vector like c(1,2,3) to a function in dplyr; dplyr functions will treat it as static instead of something to vectorize over, which is why the means differ in eipi10's example above."`: I don't think that's correct. When you do, for example, `mean(mtcars$mpg)` vs. `mean(mpg)` (the example in my answer), you're accessing `mpg` from *different* data frames: The first is the `mtcars` in the global environment. The second is the data frame passed into `mutate` by the pipe. It's not related to vectorization.

Comment: eipi10, the grouping creates individual vectors for each group to vectorize over, as I understand it, when you pass the column. I have no argument that they're different inputs--that's exactly why the first, being multiple vectors, is vectorized and second one, being a single vector, isn't. It's also not the data frame that really matters since you're extracting vectors in both cases. Plus, you'll find that if you extract `.$mpg` from the piped/grouped data frame, you still get a single vector.